# How to filter a dynamic combobox?

Tags: jquery, combobox

Im using jQuery.

```
$('#ranges').on('change', '.combo', function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var s = $(this).parent("div").attr("class");
        if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
            var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
            var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
            var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

        $('div.'+s+' .parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue !== '') {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('div.'+s).append(newComboBox);
        }
```

});

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/6/)

How can I garantee that value before is always higher than next one? May alert user to that issue or turn that combobox_text_value to "red" or prevent user to submit.

At fiddle eg. if I select 2 at first combo I should only select 3 in the next one.

ps: notice me, if you ned more code.

Dynamic combobox handling with values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/22/

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        var $newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).data('index'), 10);
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue !== '') {
            $newComboBox.data('index', newComboBoxIndex)
                        .attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex)
                        .addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex)
                        .find('option')
            .filter(function(){return this.value<=selectedValue && this.value}).remove();
            if($('option',$newComboBox).size() > 1)
               $('body').append($newComboBox);
        }
    } 

});
```

Comment: Its just a good practice to put $ in front of variable refering a jquery object. That way, each time you see a variable starting with $, you know you can apply jquery method to it.

Comment: I was using your approach, but when im handling with comboboxes, the comboindex is always the same and is causing trouble